# How are map and reduce workers in cluster selected?

Tags: mapreduce

For mapreduce job we need to specify partitioning of input data (count of map processes - M) and count of reduce processes (R). In [MapReduce papers](http://www.usenix.org/event/osdi04/tech/full_papers/dean/dean.pdf) is example of their often settings: cluster with 2 000 workers and M = 200 000, R = 5 000. Workers are tagged as map-worker or reduce-worker. I wonder how are these workers in cluster selected.

Is this done so that is chosen fixed count of map-workers and fixed count of reduce-workers? (and then data stored in reduce-workers nodes has to be send to map-reduce workers)
Or map phase is running on each node in cluster and any count of nodes are then selected as reduce-workers?
Or is it done in another way?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of Map-Worker(Mapper) depends on the number of Input-splits of the input file.

so *Ex: 200 input-splits( they are logical ) =200 Mapper*  .

**How Mapper Node  is selected ?**
The Mapper is the Local Data Node , if its not possible then data is transferred to free Node and Mapper is invoked on that node 
.

The number of Reducer can be set by the user( *Job.setNumberOfReducer(Number)* ) or else it will also be as per the number of splits of Intermediate-output of Mapper .

---

---

***Other Question's Answers***

```
Q1>so in one node can run for example 10 mappers in parallel at one time, or these mappers are processed sequentially?
```

Ans : sequentially (Max Number of (active/running)mapper =Number of DataNodes)

```
Q2>how are chosen the nodes where are reducers invoked?
```

Ans :

- Intermediate Key-Values are stored in Local File system Not in HDFS , and then it is being copied(HDFS) to Reducer Node .
- A single Mapper will feed Data to multiple reducer . so locality of data is out of the question coz a data for a particular reducer come from many Nodes if not from all .

*So Reducer is (or atleast should be) selected on Bandwidth of a Node , keeping in minds all above points*

```
 Q3>if we need reducers count bigger then overall nodes count (for example 90 reducers in 50 nodes cluster), are the reducers on one node processed in parallel or sequentially?
```

Ans : sequentially (Max Number of (active/running)Reducer =Number of DataNodes)

Comment: Ok, so in one node can run for example 10 mappers in parallel at one time, or these mappers are processed sequentially? And if we have set reducers count less than overall nodes count (for example 40 reducers in 50 nodes cluster), how are chosen the nodes where are reducers invoked? It depends on locality of intermediate outputs for the fastest data transfer or it depends on anything else? And on the other hand, if we need reducers count bigger then overall nodes count (for example 90 reducers in 50 nodes cluster), are the reducers on one node processed in parallel or sequentially?

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me, now I understand everything (I hope).